# Javascript confirmation dialog box for hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

I am new to Javascript.

For my Javascript class I'm trying to figure out how to popup a confirmation box with the "a" tags href attribute?

redirectHandler shows confirmation dialog.
Confirmation dialog shows correct href.
redirectHandler is triggered on click.
Cancel navigation.
Proceed with navigation.

This is what I have so far:

```
function clickRedirectHandler(event) {
   var attr = this.getAttribute("href"); // this === Clicked HTML element
    if (!window.confirm(attr)) { // Negate the confirm value, so if he click "cancel", it will evaluate as true
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the redirect
    }
}

function setRedirectConfirmationDialogs() {

    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i<links.length; i++){
        links[i].addEventListener('click', redirectHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can find any mistake or can put me in a direction to solve it is much appreciated rather than criticizing the question

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const reply = confirm(links[i].href);
    if (reply === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="link1">link1</a>
<a href="link2">link2</a>
<a href="link3">link3</a>
<a href="link4">link4</a>
```